# Flow property is missing in mixed passed - despite the type annotation

Tags: flowtype

I have the following in my declarations file (included in my [libs]):

```
export type EtlFieldNoIdxT = {
  name: Name,
  purpose: Purpose,
}
export type EtlFieldT = {
  idx: number,
  ...EtlFieldNoIdxT
}
```

And the following in my use of the types:

```js
export const createEtlField = (
  etlFields: { [Name]: EtlFieldT },
  newField: EtlFieldNoIdxT,
) => {
  if (etlFields === {}) {
    throw new Error({
      message: 'Cannot create a new etlField with an empty etlFields',
    });
  }

  const field: EtlFieldT = {
    idx: maxId(etlFields, 'idx') + 1,
    ...newField,
  };

  const subject: Name = Object.values(etlFields).find(
    (f) => f.purpose === 'subject',     // <<< f.purpose "missing in mixed" error
  ).name;                               // <<<  .name "missing in mixed" error

  return newEtlField(field, subject);
};
```

Despite having annotated the input, can flow not infer the type of what `Object.values` would thus return?

Thank you in advance for pointing out my misunderstanding.

- E

Answer (score 0):

If you check the declaration for `Object.values` you'll find that it returns an array of `mixed`:

`static values(object: $NotNullOrVoid): Array<mixed>;`

---

A quick google search came back with
https://davidwalsh.name/flow-object-values

So to solve your issue, you wrap `Object.values(...)` with `any`, and then inside your `find` arg you can type it as `EtlFieldT` and finally refine your type back to `EtlFieldT` after find.

```
const subject: Name = ((Object.values(etlFields): any).find(
  (f: EtlFieldT) => f.purpose === 'subject',
): EtlFieldT).name;
```

---

Though you should be aware that `find` has the possibility of returning `undefined`. So to be sound, you should run the `find`, and declare `subject` if the value exists.